# Error: Column comp.count must be length 1

Tags: r, finance

I am trying to translate R code into Matlab for Fama and French factor portfolio construction. I get the following error and I don't know what to do:

```
> # load("180619 data.ccm.RData")
> data.comp <- data.ccm %>%
+     rename(PERMNO=permno) %>% data.table %>% # ensure col names match crsp's
+     group_by(PERMNO) %>% 
+     mutate(datadate = as.yearmon(datadate),
+            comp.count = row(.)) %>% # number of years in data; future option to cut first year
+     # tests based on BE spread show FF no longer impose this condition
+     ungroup %>% arrange(datadate, PERMNO) %>% data.frame %>%
+     distinct(datadate, PERMNO, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Error: Column `comp.count` must be length 1 (the group size), not 12358968
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Full code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxvBvE2V-dFTVnZuLUFhZWNuazA/view

Best

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the number of rows by group, use `n()`

```
 mutate(datadate = as.yearmon(datadate),
        comp.count = n())
```